# Why does float print only up to 8 Digits?

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

When I am printing below statement

```
System.out.println(121.3456422f);
```

I am getting output as `121.34564` (in 8 Digits)

and if I am printing

```
System.out.println(121345642.333332f);
```

I am getting output as `1.2134564E8` (in 10 Digits including E)

I want to know why float only up to 8 digits only?

Comment: You damaged my edit. Please revert the changes and add your edits again.

Comment: Please stop undoing edits. The question should be properly formatted and that's what the community here does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default conversion of float to String produces the shortest decimal fraction that would convert back to the float on input. That will often be about 8 decimal digits, because float only has 24 bits of effective significand.

The exact value of 121.3456422f is 121.34564208984375. The largest float smaller than it is 121.34563446044921875. 121.34564 is between those values and closer to the original value than to the alternative, so 8 is enough digits.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Double for this. It's so big for float type. You may do this like:

```
System.out.println(121.3456422d);
```

JVM automatically converts all variables into restriction of types. (http://ideone.com/Pwn8yx):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class MyClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Max float value:" + Float.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println("Min float value:" + Float.MIN_VALUE);
        System.out.println("Double float value:" + Double.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println("Double float value:" + Double.MIN_VALUE);
    }
}
```

**float:** The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point.

**double:** The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point.

Look at Oracle docs about primitive types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: I know that double prints more value but I just want to know the reason Why Float prints value till 8 digit only.

Comment: so Why restriction of 8 digits with float

Comment: @Bat, **float:** The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point. And then look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the amount of digits that are printed, use the String.format() function.

For example:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%3.10f", 121.3456422f));
```

I think your precision is too high for a float. Alternatively, you can use a double and the natural toString() should print the precision you want.